# How do I ignore .DS_Store in my untracked files?

Tags: git, gitignore

I am new to Git, and every time I work with it, I always get this annoying `.DS_Store` in my untracked files. I am assuming that is where my working directory is.

I have tried searching the answer on Stack Overflow, but only found the answer on how to remove it from the repository, not from the list of untracked files.

How can I tell Git to completely ignore `.DS_Store` files and never list them as untracked files?

Comment: Have you tried adding ".DS_Store" in your .gitignore file?

Comment: Adding a `.DS_Store` entry in the project's `.gitignore` file works, but you're better off using a *global* `.gitignore` file for ignoring such OS-dependent files. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26851996/2541573

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could create a `.gitignore` file. This file tells git which file (changes) it should ignore, so they won't appear in `git status`, `git diff` etc. call.

`.gitignore` is a simple text file. Just create it in a text editor (or edit it if you already have one), and add this line:

```
.DS_Store
```

Then, you should add it to the repository, so these files are ignored by all collaborators:

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "added .gitignore"
```

Comment: Using a global gitignore is preferable for such OS-dependent files.