# Git workflow, IntelliJ project

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I've just finished git tutorial on workflow and I've setup repo for my projecct (Github, IntelliJ). I'm not feeling it yet in 100%, and got a few questions. Hope u can help me.

1) Let's say I'm working on a 'feature-A' on my PC. I need to finish it on my laptop. How to sync it? Should I just push 'feature-A' on origin and then pull it to my local repo on laptop?

2) In .gitignore I have excluded project files used by IDE (.iml, .idea, etc.). I need to clone remote repo to my laptop but I also have to setup new project in IntelliJ. How to do this right (I want to track master and develop branches).

Comment: Regarding 2), see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26851996/2541573

Answer (score 0):

1. yes, you can push it and then pull
2. IDE files usually are not committed into VCS. You did it right, now just import project sources from Git remote repository (IDEA supports GitHub or any other Git remote repository)