# Is .DS_Store file important?

Tags: git

Is .DS_Store an important hidden files?, its giving me problems with pulling from github. It is suggesting I remove it and I did. Hope this won't bite me in the butt later on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I Remove .DS\_Store files from a Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107701/how-can-i-remove-ds-store-files-from-a-git-repository)

Comment: Check [https://github.com/xiaozhuai/odourless](https://github.com/xiaozhuai/odourless), I made a tool for preventing .DS_Store.

Answer (score 20):

Just add it to `.gitignore`, the file has no relevance on other computers.

The `.DS_Store` file is used to store `Finder` information about that folder, so it's has no use in a `git` repo.

Comment: Better to add it to a global gitignore file than to the repo's `.gitignore`. See why here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26851996/2541573

Answer (score 8):

.DS_Store is a [Mac-specific hidden file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store).  It's also not something that you generally want to add to source control, as its contents *may* change without you necessarily interacting with it.

It's safest to place it into your `.gitignore` file and be done with it.  If it's already in your repository, then you can use `git rm --cached .DS_Store` to remove it from your system after it's been entered into `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 3):

From **Wikipedia**:

> In the Apple macOS operating system, .DS_Store is a file that stores
>   custom attributes of its containing folder, such as the position of
>   icons or the choice of a background image. The name is an abbreviation
>   of Desktop Services Store, reflecting its purpose. It is created and
>   maintained by the Finder application in every folder, and has
>   functions similar to the file desktop.ini in Microsoft Windows.
>   Starting with a full stop (period) character, it is hidden in Finder
>   and many Unix utilities. Its internal structure is proprietary.

You can **delete** them when you are pushing to GitHub, it will not cause any loss.
See here for more, how to remove properly - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49970762/7718859